# Casting Abstract to Interface implemented by Derived

Tags: c#, performance, interface, casting, abstract

I've heard that in c# upcasting is done at compile time, so it's really cheap to use.
But I have this situation where the type I wish to cast is abstract and it does not directly implements the interface I want it to be casted in.

Here is a sample:

```
public interface ISomething
{
   void Method();
}

public abstract class Base { }

public class Derived : Base, ISomething 
{
    public void Method() { }
}

public class OtherDerived : Base, ISomething
{
    public void Method() { }
}

public class SomeClass
{
    private Base[] _baseArray;

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        foreach (var item in _baseArray)
            ((ISomething) item).Method();
    }
}
```

Obviously, I'm in a situation where every item of `_baseArray` is actually of type that inherits from `Base` and that implements `ISomething`.
But since I can't know for sure what type every items are between `Derived`, `OtherDerived` or any other types that inherits from `Base` and implements `ISomething`, I have to use an array of the abstract base type.

Of course I could use an array of `ISomething`, but I use Unity and Interfaces will not be serialized in Edit Mode, and I need to have that array serialized.

So, now that the context is here, my question is the following :
Is casting `item` to `ISomething` handled at compile time? And if it's not, is it cheap enough to be done very often (at every frame to be exact)?

Thank you for your attention, and sorry if I'm not super clear, I'm not english so it's not really easy.

Edit : Thanks for the better title

Comment: Would having `Base` implement `ISomething` allow serialization without requiring the cast?

Comment: Yeah it would, but in my situation the types that inherit from `Base` don't always implements `ISomething`. I have plenty of other interfaces (and plenty of other `SomeMethod` pattern with theses other interfaces) that `Base` derived types can implements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see the IL that your C# compiles down to: [SharpLab IL Results](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgNAJiDUAfAAgZgARgHbAKYCcAzAQwGNd0BJAZQHsBbXYAC2wHMBYAKAG9v0ByACzoAsk2a0YACgCUAbm4BfbtzTpiAIwDOwfGWDpkAJnQAhYtoo90Krmown0AEQJgAbrhjoQ5y7igqOkYWdnRuPi4BQUcRcRYpOXQbOzsHI1MAeRYCV3wPLx8/K0CaBgl2CP5o9WExCUTZZNtlVS5a02DcAGEIS20qqOiAB3z3Yjxi3ABtAF10AH1NfwBBfH0AT0V7IZijES74yRlZaoFI6Mv0Qlp8XDJmdGlx/Ew8ekwsReWrNc3T3ZXS7SaRlEKsLBsJpgd6yAB0R0a20uqW4QA)

Your loop:

```
    // loop start (head: IL_0021)
        IL_000d: ldloc.0
        IL_000e: ldloc.1
        IL_000f: ldelem.ref
        IL_0010: stloc.2
        IL_0011: ldloc.2
        IL_0012: castclass ISomething
        IL_0017: callvirt instance void ISomething::Method()
        IL_001c: nop
        // sequence point: hidden
        IL_001d: ldloc.1
        IL_001e: ldc.i4.1
        IL_001f: add
        IL_0020: stloc.1

        IL_0021: ldloc.1
        IL_0022: ldloc.0
        IL_0023: ldlen
        IL_0024: conv.i4
        IL_0025: blt.s IL_000d
    // end loop
```

`Method()` is called using `callvirt`, which basically means a dispatch. In this case, it's because the specific type of your object is not known at *compile time*.

I wouldn't worry about the performance of this, though, unless you profile and you see that this particular code is a hotspot.

Comment: Yeah I thought so, thanks for this answer.
It indeed seems to have no performance issue in this context, so I'll stick with what I have here.